# Split a string into letters

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift2, xcode7

Suppose I have a `String` - `"Hello"`
How can I split the `String` into an `Array` which holds each `character` like this - `["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"]`
Thanks.

Comment: This is actually an **_exact_** duplicate of the question luk2302 mentioned. Even the example string is the same

Comment: But the wordings of the title is more perfect. May be thats why 15+ people marked as useful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The characters in a string is put under the `characters` collection. Just iterate over them and convert them to `String`:

#### Swift 4

```
let str =  "Hello"
let arr = str.map { String($0) }
print(arr)
```

#### Swift 3

```
let str =  "Hello"
let arr = str.characters.map { String($0) }
print(arr)
```

Comment: Or just `Array(str.characters)`

Comment: @Arc676 the difference is that your code yields a Character Array while his answer yields a String Array

Comment: `Array(str.characters)` creates an array of `Character`.  Harder to work with down the road

Comment: Just to clarify for those reading this: The expression `str.characters` gives an array of `Character` structs. The code `str.characters.map { String($0) }` creates an array of characters and then maps that array back to an array of single-charater `String` objects.

Answer (score -4):

I think you'll have to do it somewhat manually.

```
NSString *str = @"Hello";
NSMutableArray *chars = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [str length]; i++) {
    unichar c = [str characterAtIndex:i];
    [chars addObject:[NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1]]; 
}
```

Comment: Question is asked for Swift..

Comment: Wrong language and wrong statement.

Comment: The OP is asking for a solution in Swift, where handling of characters from a string is different, slightly more complicated, and has changed slightly in Swift 2. I'm not that familiar with Swift 2 yet, so I'm going to let somebody who IS up on Swift 2 answer this.

Comment: This is for Obj-C. The question uses Swift 2 (which gives you the array of characters with `str.characters`)

Comment: I still don't follow you.  I missed the language thing and assumed Objective-C, but I don't know a better way in Objective-C, do you?

Comment: @luk2302 I'll take your silence as "No, I don't know a better way, so iterating manually is the only way in Objective-C".

Comment: Posting a answer in the wrong language and then claiming that your statements are actually true in that (wrong) language is just ... I don't know ... just still very much wrong. If I post a CJam answer and say that you can do that with only one letter - then that is true BUT achieves nothing. So while you might be correct in Objective-C that does just simply not matter.

Comment: @luk2302 Yes, I've acknowledged my answer as being for the wrong language.  It's the "wrong statement" part of your comment I am asking about and you have yet to demonstrate it as incorrect (again, for Objective-C).

Comment: It isn't incorrect for Objective-C but it is incorrect for the question asked since Objective-C is irrelevant here.